# Add secrets from secrets.json to configuration when EnvironmentName is "Local"

Tags: c#, .net, configuration

When working with user secrets stored in secrets.json in .NET 6,

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
var app = builder.Build();
```

`WebApplication.CreateBuilder` initializes a new instance of the `WebApplicationBuilder` class with preconfigured defaults. The initialized `WebApplicationBuilder` (builder) provides default configuration and calls `AddUserSecrets` when the `EnvironmentName` is `Development`.

Is there a way to override this so that `AddUserSecrets` is called on `EnvironmentName` = "Local"?

Answer (score 1):

```
if (!builder.Environment.IsLocal())
{
// Read from different source like Key Vault
}
{
//read from User secrets
builder.Configuration.AddUserSecrets(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());   
}
```